# Spark / Scala : fill consecutive missing values in a row of a dataframe using preceding and following values

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Using Databricks, Spark 3.0.1

To use the legacy format, I have set:
`spark.conf.set("spark.sql.legacy.timeParserPolicy","LEGACY")`

I have gone through many similar posts on SO, but none is close enough to my problem, so that I can infer a solution.

I have a dataframe with consecutive null values in some rows that need to be replaced. I **cannot use the median or mean value.** Instead,

> the **first** half needs to be filled with the value from the **preceding** non-null column. 
> the **second** half needs to be filled with the value from the **following** non-null column.

For **odd number** of missing values,

> if there is only **one** missing value, using the **preceding value** is fine. 
> the missing value in the "**middle**" can be replaced by the **preceding value**.

Issues with the solutions I have read so far:

1. Missing values are replaced using non-null values from the same column, whereas I **need to use non-values from the same row.**
2. I can't transpose the dataframe since I have more than **40 million different ids and not more than 30 columns**. Unfortunately, using pandas for that task is not possible because it isn't scalable.

**Sample :**

```
+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
|id  |col1|col2|col3|col4|col5|col6|col5|col6|
+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
|1   |100 |100 |null|null|null|null|200 |200 |
|2   |180 |180 |null|null|300 |300 |300 |300 |
|3   |400 |400 |400 |400 |null|200 |200 |200 |
|4   |700 |700 |null|null|null|200 |200 |200 |
+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
```

**Expected Output :**

```
+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
|id  |col1|col2|col3|col4|col5|col6|col5|col6|
+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
|1   |100 |100 |100 |100 |200 |200 |200 |200 |
|2   |180 |180 |180 |300 |300 |300 |300 |300 |
|3   |400 |400 |400 |400 |400 |200 |200 |200 |
|4   |700 |700 |700 |700 |200 |200 |200 |200 |
+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
```

Comment: One way is to create an array from col1 through colN, and then use an UDF to fill the nulls. For Python, we can use pd.Series.interpolate(method='nearest') which does exactly what you are looking for. https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.interpolate.html

Comment: Thanks for your reply, your suggestion is interesting, I will give it a try. I wish I could use pandas, that would make my life so much easier.

Comment: Posted answer to other question